# Loops within Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a question regarding loops within python.

What i want to do is the following thing:

```
# init
list = [a,b,c,d..]
length_list = len(list)

# compare object a with object b, note that the python code
# in object b is not valid, but to clearify my question a put 
# it that way
object a = list[0]
object b = list[1,2,3.....,2000]

# create a loop that compares object a with all the values within object b
# so you will get: 
# iteration 1: A compared with B
# iteration 2: A compared with C 
# iteration 3: A compared with D
# iteration x: A compared with ...
# etc. 
for comparing in range(len(list)):
    .......
    .......
    ....... (need help here)

# After the for loop has reached the end after 2000 iteration
# The loop should begin again but then with the following properties:
# Increment object a with 1 (object a = list [1])
# and compare again object a with all the other options within object b
# so you will get: 
# Iteration 1: B compared with C, 
# Iteration 2: B compared with D, 
# Iteration 3: B compared with E
# etc.
# (note that we do not want to check B with A because we allready did that)
```

The question how can i do that? So that the value within my *object_a* only get incremented by 1 after 2000 runs and then run again until *object_a* also reached the value of 2000.

If still things are unclear please ask.

Comment: what do you mean by "compare"? What do you mean by "compare `a` with all values of object `b`"?

Comment: what i have is that I have a list, stored with all music artist. what i want to do is like:
Artist A comparing with Artist B. 

the comparing part is done with an api, i just need a structure where i can check Artist A with all the other Artists and if the loop is done, just increment Artist A with 1 so that i will become Artist B and compare Artist B with all the other Artists in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a nested for loop. Something like:

```
for i in range(len(list) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(list)):
        #compare list[i] with list[j]
```

Comment: This exactly what i wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate(list) to get index of list.
It returns (index, value) by pair, and you can use it

`for index, x in enumerate(list):
    for y in list[index+1:]: 
        #compare x and y`